# How to end iter_rows loop when cell value is empty?

Tags: python-3.x, openpyxl

I am trying to iterate through cells and then stop the loop when I hit the first empty cell.

For this purpose I wrote the loop:

```
best_ten = []
for row in sheet.iter_rows(min_row=1, max_col=1, max_row=100):
    for cell in row:
        if cell.value:
            best_ten.append(cell.value)
        else:
            break
```

However, the empty cells just get skipped. I want the loop to end when the first empty cell is hit.

How can I achieve that?

Cheers

Comment: How about using `return`? Can you post your whole function so we can show you how

Comment: `break` will break you only out of the current loop, so you'll move into the next row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a return statement within a function, you can break out of both for loops:

```
def find_best_ten():
    best_ten = []
    for row in sheet.iter_rows(min_row=1, max_col=1, max_row=100):
        for cell in row:
            if cell.value:
                best_ten.append(cell.value)
            else:
                return best_ten
    return best_ten
```